# Matplotlib animation saves only one part of the video with ffmpeg

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a weird problem with Python Matplotlib animation. I want to produce a video which includes another small video in the corner: the bigger plot should animate some data, and the small inserted plot should indicate with a moving dashed line the time position on the global data plot. It all works fine when I use only plot.show(), just the way I want it. But when I comment plot.show() and try to save it with ani.save, all it saves is a big plot, and the inserted one just disappears!

If I try to uncomment both ani.save and plot.show() at the same time, I get an error message "AttributeError: draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which caches the render", and the animation screen just stays blank.

Could you please help me how to solve it? I need a saved file with the full movie.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

Q_data = np.arange(100.).reshape((10,10))
age = np.arange(10.)
Q_total = np.arange(10.)

Q = Q_data[1:,:] 
r_ax = np.arange(10.)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.semilogy(r_ax,Q[0,:])
time_template = 'time = %.1f'
time_text = ax.text(0.58, 0.9, '', size=20, transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.title('Plot 1')
ax.set_xlabel('Axis Title')
ax.set_ylabel('Axis Title')
# this is another inset axes over the main axes    
a = plt.axes([0.2, 0.5, .3, .3])
line2, = plt.semilogx(age,Q_total,color='r',linewidth=1)    
plt.title('Plot 2', y=1.11)
a.set_xlabel('Small axis title')
#fig.canvas.draw()

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(Q[i,:])  # update the data
    time_text.set_text(time_template % (age[i])) 
    a.lines.pop()
    a.semilogx(age,Q_total,color='r',linewidth=1)  
    a.axvline(age[i], color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)        


    return line, a, time_text

# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(r_ax, mask=True))
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line, time_text    


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, Q.shape[0], 1),     init_func=init, interval=25, blit=True)

ani.save('testanimation.avi', writer="ffmpeg", fps=15)                                 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made you a small example with big axis and small axis inside it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'D:\ffmpeg-20161029-1e660fe-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe'
import matplotlib.animation as animation

r_ax = np.arange(1, 10., 0.1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(r_ax, np.log(r_ax))
a = plt.axes([0.2, 0.5, .3, .3])
line2, = a.plot([], [],color='r',linewidth=1)
a.set_xlim([1, 10])
a.set_ylim([0, 3])

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(r_ax[:i], np.log(r_ax[:i]))  # update the data
    line2.set_data(r_ax[:i], 3-np.log(r_ax[:i]))

    return line, line2

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=35, blit=True)
ani.save('testanimation.avi', writer="ffmpeg", fps=15)

# plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! However, this code has a similar problem as mine, although is written much better: when I open the saved file, I see only frames, but no moving lines. They are not saved for some reason. Plt.show() shows everything properly, but not the .avi file.

Comment: My code works for me and the .avi file shows the moving lines. I use python 2.7.11, matplotlib 1.5.1, ffmpeg 3.1.5. I tried also python 3.5.1 and the other the same and it works as well.

Comment: see my edited answer (I just commented out the last line)

Comment: Now it works, thanks! The problem was that I inserted a wrong path in animation.ffmpeg_path. Thank you so much for your help!